# Wildcard on Nginx Content Security Policy

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I'm updating an Nginx config file trying to use a wildcard on a Content Security Policy definition.

I need to allow "https://cdn.rollbar.com/rollbarjs/refs/tags/v2.15.2/rollbar.min.js;" and if I hardcode it everything works fine.

However, I'd like to use a wildcard so I allow all the versions (and I don't have to update the config when a new version is released and required by the app).

I have tried something like

https://cdn.rollbar.com/rollbarjs/refs/tags/*/rollbar.min.js;
https://cdn.rollbar.com/rollbarjs/*;

But neither works.

How can I use a wildcard?

Comment: Have you tried just stop at the `/`. Example: `https://cdn.rollbar.com/rollbarjs/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, no wildcard at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the domain name like this `script-src: https://cdn.rollbar.com;`

It will allow script files from that URL.